# Dynamic Fixed TH Optimization - How to hide the rendering of re-sizing of widths of th cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title suggests, I have a working but **not optimized fixed header table** which resizes the cells of the table after all the rows are loaded.

I want the user not to see the re-sizing to occur and directly show the table.

But the problem is that it takes too long and there is no table visible for a while until all rows are displayed and until the jQuery events fire to resize.

I want to hold on to the previous DOM or some how keep the previous page buffer on the screen until the resize occurs at which point I want to run the show event in jQuery.

How can I achieve this desired outcome or, if not, what approach will help make a more efficient fixed header table render that does not show the user the re-sizing of the table cells to the user?

**PHP Serverside Width Calculation Code**

```
$visibleCols = array_diff($cols, $excludeCols, $hideCols);

foreach($visibleCols as $cidx=>$col)
{
    if (colIsCategoryField($col, $categoryNames))
        $visibleCols[] = $manageActionItems->getCategoryName($col);
}

foreach($visibleCols as $cidx=>$col)
{
    $thWidth[$col] = 0;
    $maxTDWidth[$col] = 0;
}

foreach($resAll as $idx=>$row)
{
    foreach ($visibleCols as $cidx=>$col)
    {
        $td = trim(preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", " ", $row[$col]));
        $length = (imagefontwidth($fontSize)) * strlen($td);

        if ($length > $maxTDWidth[$col])
        {
            $maxTDWidth[$col] = $length;
        }
    }
}
foreach ($visibleCols as $cidx=>$col)
{
    $th = ($cidx == 0)? "ID":$col;
    $thlen = (imagefontwidth($fontSize)) * strlen($th);
    $thWidth[$col] = $thlen;
}

foreach($visibleCols as $cidx=>$col)
{
    if ($cidx == 0)
        $width[$col] = 34;
    else
        $width[$col] = (max($maxTDWidth[$col], $thWidth[$col]) *.60) + 25;
}
```

?>

**jQuery Column Width Code**

```
function setColWidth(id_header, id_table)
{
            $("table#"+id_header).attr("style", "opacity: 0");
            $("table#"+id_table).attr("style", "opacity: 0");
            headers = $("table#"+id_header+" thead tr td");
            topcols = $("table#"+id_table+" tbody tr:first td");
            topcolvals = $("table#"+id_table+" tbody tr:first td input");
            headervals = $("table#"+id_header+" thead tr:first td input");

        $('div.'+id_header+'#'+id_header).attr('style', 'max-width:' + $('div.'+id_header+"#"+id_table).width());    

            for (var colidx = 0; colidx < $(headers).size(); colidx++)
            {
                    headerwidth = $(headers[colidx]).width();
                    topcolwidth = $(topcols[colidx]).width();


                    if (headerwidth > topcolwidth && !$(headervals[colidx]).attr('value'))
                    {
                        $(topcols[colidx]).attr('style',  'width: ' +  headerwidth + 'px; min-width:'+ headerwidth + 'px');
                        $(headers[colidx]).attr('style', 'width: ' +  headerwidth + 'px; min-width:'+ headerwidth + 'px');

                        $(topcolvals[colidx]).attr('value', headerwidth);
                        $(headervals[colidx]).attr('value', headerwidth);
                    }
                    else if (headerwidth < topcolwidth && !$(topcolvals[colidx]).attr('value'))
                    {
                        $(topcols[colidx]).attr('style',  'width: ' +  topcolwidth + '; min-width:'+ topcolwidth + 'px');
                        $(headers[colidx]).attr('style', 'width: ' +  topcolwidth + '; min-width:'+ topcolwidth + 'px');

                        $(topcolvals[colidx]).attr('value', topcolwidth);
                        $(headervals[colidx]).attr('value', topcolwidth);
                    }
            }
            $("table#"+id_header).attr("style", "opacity: 1");
            $("table#"+id_table).attr("style", "opacity: 1");
    }
```

**PHP/HTML Table Code**

```
<div class="summary_header <?=getHeaderClass($resAll);?>">
<table id="summary_header" border=1>
    <thead class="header">     
            <tr> 
                <th class="edit">
                    Edit&nbsp;
                </th>           
                <?php foreach ($cols as $cidx=>$col): ?>
                        <?php if (!in_array($col, $hideCols) || $col == 'ActionItemID'): ?>
                            <th <?//=getWidth($cidx)?>>
                            <? if (in_array($col, $categoryNames)):?>
                                <a onclick="$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=<?=$col?>&dir=<?=getDir($dir, $col)?>');$('#summaryform').submit();"><?=$manageActionItems->getCategoryName($col)?></a>
                                <?=getArrow($orderBy, $col, $dir)?>
                            <?else:?>
                                <a onclick="$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=<?=$col?>&dir=<?=getDir($dir, $col)?>');$('#summaryform').submit();"><?=($col=="ActionItemID")?"ID": $col?></a>
                                <?=getArrow($orderBy, $col, $dir)?>
                            <?endif?>
                            </th>                                                                     
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could try building the table in memory on the server side and then echoing the whole thing at once.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am wondering if my approach is wrong to begin with.  Because I load then I process the table widths. However, perhaps I need to calculate the widths on the server beforehand as you are suggesting.

Comment: So the calculations of the column widths take longer than the building of the table? Hm.

Comment: I am close to solving the issue with the width calculation code.  Now I can't prevent the extra space inside each td/th to the right of the inner text from being added regardless of the actual length of the content of the cells.  How do I force prevention of extra td or th space in each cell when the page finishes rendering?